# How to modify macOS BigSur system sounds?

Tags: macos, audio, big-sur

I recently updated to macOS BigSur and discovered the sounds are awful!

How can I replace them with the old ones?

I know they are in  `/System/Library/Components/CoreAudio.component` but I can't replace them. 
How can I force to replace them?
What do I have as options?

Answer (score 5):

You can add your own sounds to `~/Library/Sounds`, the one in your Home folder, and they will then appear in System Preferences > Sounds > Sound Effects, and in the Mail.app's Preferences.

Apple is making modification of the system files increasingly difficult, for security.

Comment: RE: "Apple is making modification of the system files increasingly difficult, for security." --  Yeah, but did we ask for that!? +1

Comment: @user3439894 "ask for"? perhaps not, but need? given some of the errors that users post on here, then the more safety additions the better. No wonder It professionals have the id10t joke or pebcak ...

Answer (score 0):

I've mixed up two tabs here, and erroneously posted the solution for 12.2.5 in here. It's possible that it will work, however: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/446578/177613

Can't post comments on askdifferent, sorry.

As per Alper's request, the basic rundown is that (on Monterey) you need to

- disable authenticated-root (and probably SIP) in recovery mode,
- identify and mount the volume with `sudo mount -o nobrowse -t apfs /dev/diskXsY ~/YOURMOUNTFOLDER` (replacing diskXsY according to your config)
- apply your changes inside `~/YOURMOUNTFOLDER`
- and afterwards create a snapshot and mark it for boot with `sudo /System/Library/Filesystems/apfs.fs/Contents/Resources/apfs_systemsnapshot -v ~/YOURMOUNTFOLDER -s "YOURSNAPSHOTNAME"` and `sudo /System/Library/Filesystems/apfs.fs/Contents/Resources/apfs_systemsnapshot -v ~/YOURMOUNTFOLDER -r "YOURSNAPSHOTNAME"`

It looks like this will keep you from enabling filevault.

Comment: Pls explain the solution you are proposing with enough detail here so that someone can still benefit in case the link gets broken in the future.